# Indexing a Vec of Box Error

Tags: rust

I was playing around with the `Vec` struct and ran into some interesting errors and behavior that I can't quite understand. Consider the [following code](http://is.gd/qKK8wy).

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![box 1i];
    let f = v[0];
}
```

When evaluated in the rust playpen, the code produces the following errors:

```
<anon>:3:13: 3:17 error: cannot move out of dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
<anon>:3     let f = v[0];
                     ^~~~
<anon>:3:9: 3:10 note: attempting to move value to here (to prevent the move, use `ref f` or `ref mut f` to capture value by reference)
<anon>:3     let f = v[0];
                 ^
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
Program ended.
```

My understanding of `Vec`'s [`index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.index) method is that it returns references to the values in a `Vec`, so I don't understand what moves or implicit dereferences are happening.

Also, when I [change the `f` variable to an underscore](http://is.gd/A9Zhac), as below, no errors are produced!

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![box 1i];
    let _ = v[0];
}
```

I was hoping someone could explain the errors I was getting and why they go away when switching `f` to `_`.

Comment: Indexing was just added for Vec and I think it might not be working correctly in all cases. I'm guessing that the assignment to underscore is a no-op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea which syntax sugar `v[0]` implements, but it is trying to move the value instead of getting a reference.

But if you call `.index()`, it works and gives you a reference with the same lifetime of the vector:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![box 1i];
    let f = v.index(&0);
    println!("{}", f);
}
```

The second example works because as the value is being discarded, it doesn't try to move it.

EDIT:

The desugar for `v[0]` is `*v.index(&0)` (from: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/fb72c4767fa423649feeb197b50385c1fa0a6fd5/src/librustc/middle/trans/expr.rs#L467 ).

```
fn main() { 
    let a = vec!(1i);
    let b = a[0] == *a.index(&0);
    println!("{}" , b);
}

true
```

Comment: Ah, knowing its `*v.index(&0)`, the implicit dereference and move errors make a lot of sense. Thanks @snf!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `let f = v[0];` assigns f by value (as said in the error message, it is implicitly dereferencing) : the compiler tries to copy or move `v[0]` into `f`. `v[0]` being a `box`, it cannot be copied, thus it should be moved like in this situation :

```
let a = box 1i;
let b = a;
// a cannot be used anymore, it has been moved
// following line would not compile
println!("{}", a);
```

But values cannot be moved out of the vector via indexing, as it is a reference that is returned.

Concerning `_`, this code :

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![box 1i];
    let _ = v[0];
    println!("{}", _);
}
```

produces this error :

```
<anon>:4:20: 4:21 error: unexpected token: `_`
<anon>:4     println!("{}", _);
                            ^
```

`_` is not a variable name but a special name of rust, telling you don't care about the value, so the compiler doesn't try to copy or move anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your original function to work by de-referencing your v[0]:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![box 1i];
    let f = &v[0]; // notice the &
    println!("{}",f);
}
```

I don't know why the underscore silences your error. It should probably raise an error since the underscore alone is an invalid variable name (I think). Attempting to print it yields an error:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![box 1i];
    let _ = &v[0];
    println!("{}",_);
}
```

Output:

```
<anon>:4:19: 4:20 error: unexpected token: `_`
<anon>:4     println!("{}",_);
```

The underscore is used to silence unused variable warnings (for example the compiler will yell at you if you define **some_var** and never use it, but won't if you define **_some_var** and never use it). It is also used as a fallback in a match statement to match anything that did not match other paths:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![box 1i];
    let f = &v[0];
    match **f {
        3i => println!("{}",f),
        _ => println!("nothing here")
    };
}
```

Someone smarter than me should comment on if the underscore is a valid variable name. Honestly I think the compiler shouldn't allow it.

Comment: `_` is not a valid variable name, it's just a pattern.